# json.net query criteria on selecttoken

Tags: json, json.net

I have a json document with nodes on the root element that are not collections, just simple object like

```
{
  "Something": {"Code": "ABC"},
  "SomethingElse": {"Code": "ABC"}
}
```

I'm trying to use SelectToken to get "Something" if and only if Code matches with a certain criteria or null otherwise, so I'm trying

```
 obj.SelectToken("$.Something[?(@.Code == 'ABC')]")
```

but it isn't working, its null everytime. How is this supposed to work when not dealing with collections?

Comment: There may not be a way to do this with JSONPath. Maybe using LINQ to JSON would be better here.

Comment: I wanted to store these things on a web config hence the need for it to be a jsonpath string. I ended up wrapping the document on another document with surrogate collection so I can use selectors.